# mysql inserts a • via PHP as gibberish but works directly through mysql

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

This PHP code:

```
$db = new mysqli($hostname,$username, $password, $dbname)    
$sql = "insert into table (column1) values ('•')";
$db->query($sql);
```

results in this in my DB: `â€¢`

However, if I try this directly in MySQL

```
insert into table (Column1) values ('•');
```

It accurately inserts `•`

What's PHP doing here? The DB and table structure are both UTF8_general_ci.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind. Simply inserting this line solved it:

```
 mysqli_set_charset($db,"utf8");
```